# How to Adjust LiveData from Room Database Before It's Assigned to a Variable

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I'm teaching myself Kotlin, based on some very old coding knowledge, so I might be missing something very obvious.

Basically, I want to adjust some LiveData slightly, every time it's returned from the Room database. The LiveData is a key value pair, and I want to make sure the key is assigned even if the requested item isn't in the database, so the LiveData is never null. I've tried a number of ways to do this -- most recently with a LiveData builder, but it tends to return null the first time, and then never updates. I think the problem I'm having (which I expected the LiveData builder to solve) is that the LiveData isn't returned from the database in time to make the adjustments.

I know I can do this with two LiveData objects -- observing the one that comes direct from the database, and then performing the adjustments before assigning it to a second variable -- but I'll be doing this with a large number of variables and there must be a cleaner way.

Here's the last thing I tried.

In ViewModel:

```
    val myLiveData = liveData {
        val rawLiveData = database.get("key")
        emit(myDataClass("key", rawLiveData.value?.plotInput.toString().trim()))
    }
```

In DAO

```
    @Query("SELECT * from database_table WHERE key = :key")
    fun get(key: String): LiveData<myDataClass?>
```

I hope this is clear, and not too dumb of a question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the recommended way to do this is through Transformations—see https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data-transformations#0 for details.

That said, LiveData appears to be on the way out (Android moves fast!) and you might want to consider using https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I misunderstood what transformations are for. I also thought that flow was for strings of values rather than for a single value, but I must have been wrong. I'll look into these!

Answer (score 3):

Returning liveDate from a Room query is not the properly good way. LiveDate is a lifecycle component, it's better do not to use it in logic.

There are better alternatives like **Flow**. It is Reactive and more cleaner. Also, you can use Coroutines by just adding the **suspend** keyword to the method signature and returning the model class itself.